Robot Framework cant get text from a paragraph element
I'm having problems obtaining a text string from a locator in Robot Framework. I actually have two strings I'm trying to get, one will work and the other wont. They seem very similar apart from one is inside a paragraph locator so I must be missing something for the paragraph one.
Here is the element for the first string that I can successfully obtain:
<div class="title" data-testid="title_name">Test String 1 is here</div>

And here is the element for the second string that I am having problems obtaining:
<p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body1 css-rq5qtz xh-highlight" data-testid="message">Test String 2 is here</p>

Here is my code from Robot Framework where I am trying to get these strings and set them to a variable using the Selenium keyword 'Get Text':
${locator1} =  //*[@data-testid="title_name"]
${locator2} =  //*[@data-testid="message"]

${getString1}=  Get Text   ${locator1}
${getString2}=  Get Text   ${locator2}

Variable ${getString1} is successfully set as "Test String 1 is here"
But variable ${getString2} is empty.
What am I missing here please?

Given that you referred to the div and p elements using a wildcard (*) which would match any element, there's no practical difference, and both XPath expressions should work. I honestly feel like you must have missed something out of the your example. Can you provide the full HTML document as a code block, or via a URL, instead of just the two excerpts?
